# Remove everything between specific characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript from the following string

filterExpress = %1 and %2 and %3 and % and %5 and %6
I need to remove anything following "% " (i.e % and a space) and before the immediately next occurrence of %.

So the output string should be-

%1 and %2 and %3 and %5 and %6
I've tried to use regexp as follows

filterExpress = filterExpress.replace(/ % .*[^%]/, '');
However, this doesn't match the results that I want.

Please help me giving a solution.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please be more specific in what should result when running this code, and also providing attempts to solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry new to the forum and just started using javascript filterExpress = "%1 and %2 and %3 and % and %5 and %6" and output should be "%1 and %2 and %3 and %5 and %6". I have tried filterExpress = filterExpress.replace(/ % .*[^%]/, '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short solution:

```
var str = '%1 and %2 and %3 and % and %5 and %6';
str.replace(/% .*?%/g, '%'); // "%1 and %2 and %3 and %5 and %6"
```

Regexp explained:
matches anything starting with `%[space]` until the first `%`. It has the global modifier so it doesn't stop after the first match. It matched both %, so one of them is in the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Regex that doesn't match the last %

```
var str='%1 and %2 and %3 and % and %5 and %6';
str=str.replace(/% .+?(?=%)/g,'');
//Match a % followed by a space than then any character until the next %
//but not including it.  Also, do a global replace.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = '%1 and %2 and %3 and % and %6';
var newStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    var c = str[i];
    if(c === '%' && str[i+1] === ' '){
        i += ' and '.length;
        continue;
    }
    newStr += c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any the following-

### code(using regexp) [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zmu9g/)

```
var str = '%1 and %2 and %3 and % and %5 and %6';
str=str.replace(/% [^%]+%/g, '%'); // "%1 and %2 and %3 and %5 and %6"
alert(str);
```

### code(not using regexp) [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNZEc/)

```
var filterExpress = "%1 and %2 and %3 and % and %5 and %6";

//start of logic
while(filterExpress.indexOf("% ")!=-1)
{
    filterExpress=filterExpress.substr(0, filterExpress.indexOf("% "))+filterExpress.substr(filterExpress.indexOf("%",filterExpress.indexOf("% ")+1));
}
//end of logic

alert(filterExpress);
```